# How do I change Mac OS X's sleep behavior with respect to USB plugging/unplugging?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, usb

If a USB device is plugged or unplugged, my MacBook Pro wakes up from sleep. Can this behavior be changed somehow? That is to say, I do not want my Mac to wake up when a USB device is unplugged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the Mac awakes is because the USB device is drawing power from the Mac’s USB port. When you disconnect it, there’s a change in the voltage and the Mac awakes (same goes when you plug one).

Curiously, there’s a way to do it in Windows.

According to the guys at [Super User, this is not possible on a Mac](https://superuser.com/q/28580/3349). At least not that we’ve discovered yet.

Comment: What a bummer... This is annoying, especially when I'm charging my phone from the Mac and then put the Mac to sleep but forget to unplug the phone.

Comment: @Pawel in Lion I think that the display stays off now, which is something. :p I'd have to do some more testing to confirm this.